# A call to SSPI failed

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I am using MySQL connector 6.9.11 and it connects to db in my linux server. Today suddenly I get error "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.". Inner exp is "The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted".

My code is in VS 2010 and uses .net 4.0

```
connStr = String.Format("server={0};user id={1}; password={2}", "www.mysite.com", UN, PW)
Conn = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
Conn.Open()
```

Server type: MySQL

Server connection: SSL is not being used

Server version: 5.7.43 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Please help me fix it.

Comment: Not really sure on exact cause, but my guess since it's suddenly stopped working is more environmental on your DB server/Linux config.  Can you connect to this db from your dev machine using any DB management software?  You might be better off in the super user stack

Comment: Investigation revealed error "Bad handshake". MySQL was upgraded from5.7.42 to 5.7.43 and this causes mysql connector 6.9.11 to stop working. Since my programs use .net framework 4, I dont know what to do.

Comment: Guess two simplest options then.  1) upgrade the client to use a compatible connector. 2) Downgrade server back to 5.7.42

Comment: Yes, I think I will downgrade back to 5.7.42